# Why would Mongoose be saving the same document multiple times?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

(Having discovered the answer, I've pared down my question to remove the less relevant bits, so that it will be more readable/useful to any future readers.)

---

I'm testing out my schema/models in Mongoose to see if they work as expected. They do, mostly, except I've found that I sometimes end up with the same documents being saved multiple times.

I'll walk through what I'm trying. First I load the model and confirm that the collection is empty:

```
var Artist = require('model-Artist');
Artist.find({}, function(err, docs) {
    docs.forEach(function(doc) { doc.remove(); }); // delete all docs to be safe
});
Artist.count({}, console.log); // => null 0
```

Alright, so the collection is empty. Then I create a new document using `new` with the mongoose model:

```
var nedRorem = new Artist();
nedRorem.names.push({
    sort: 'Rorem, Ned',
    display: 'Ned Rorem',
    brief: 'Rorem',
    personal: true
});
nedRorem.born = { year: 1923, month: 10, date: 23 };
nedRorem.places.push('USA');
```

At this point I check to see how the doc looks:

```
> nedRorem
{ born: Mon Oct 22 1923 20:28:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
  _id: 522a0694e9a7813c23000020,
  specialGenres: [],
  seeAlso: [],
  memberOf: [],
  places: [ 'USA' ],
  ensemble: false,
  names:
   [ { sort: 'Rorem, Ned',
       display: 'Ned Rorem',
       brief: 'Rorem',
       _id: 522a0694e9a7813c23000035,
       index: true,
       personal: true } ] }
```

Looks good. Note the _id. Then I save, and check the count:

```
nedRorem.save();
Artist.count({}, console.log); // => null 1
```

Excellent! Let's begin creating another artist:

```
var catharineCrozier = new Artist();
catharineCrozier.names.push({
    sort: 'Crozier, Catharine',
    display: 'Catharine Crozier',
    personal: true
});
```

Note that I haven't saved the new one yet. But how many Artists are there now?

```
Artist.count({}, console.log); // => null 3
```

!!??? So who are they?

```
Artist.find({}, console.log);
> null [ { born: Mon Oct 22 1923 20:28:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    _id: 522a08a7af52934c1200000a,
    __v: 0,
    specialGenres: [],
    seeAlso: [],
    memberOf: [],
    places: [ 'USA' ],
    ensemble: false,
    names:
     [ { sort: 'Rorem, Ned',
         display: 'Ned Rorem',
         brief: 'Rorem',
         _id: 522a08a7af52934c1200000b,
         index: true,
         personal: true } ] },
  { born: Mon Oct 22 1923 20:28:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    _id: 522a08a8af52934c1200000d,
    __v: 0,
    specialGenres: [],
    seeAlso: [],
    memberOf: [],
    places: [ 'USA' ],
    ensemble: false,
    names:
     [ { sort: 'Rorem, Ned',
         display: 'Ned Rorem',
         brief: 'Rorem',
         _id: 522a08a8af52934c1200000e,
         index: true,
         personal: true } ] },
  { born: Mon Oct 22 1923 20:28:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
    _id: 522a08a8af52934c12000010,
    __v: 0,
    specialGenres: [],
    seeAlso: [],
    memberOf: [],
    places: [ 'USA' ],
    ensemble: false,
    names:
     [ { sort: 'Rorem, Ned',
         display: 'Ned Rorem',
         brief: 'Rorem',
         _id: 522a08a8af52934c12000011,
         index: true,
         personal: true } ] } ]
```

There are three documents of the first Artist, and they all have different ._id's from the original one I created.

So here's where I define the Artist Schema:

```
var artistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    names: [{
        sort: String,
        display: String,
        brief: String,
        nonLatin: String,
        personal: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        index: { type: Boolean, default: true }
    }],

    born: ucaDate(true),
    died: ucaDate(),

    ensemble: { type: Boolean, index: true, default: false },
    places: { type: [ String ], index: true },
    memberOf: [ { type: ObjectID, ref: 'Artist' } ],
    seeAlso: [ { type: ObjectID, ref: 'Artist' } ],

    specialGenres: [{
        name: String,
        parent: String,
        classical: Boolean
    }]
});
```

What gives?

Comment: please post your complete script somewhere like jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I got it! I had a property in my schema named 'index':

```
names: [{
    sort: String,
    display: String,
    brief: String,
    nonLatin: String,
    personal: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    index: { type: Boolean, default: true }
}],
```

`index` is used in Mongoose to indicate whether a document property should be indexed by MongoDB, and I was using it here as the name of a normal document property. Changing the name of the property to `showInIndex` fixed it. It was a foolish error, but I think that the effect it had is pretty surprising so this answer may prove useful to someone in the future. (Does anyone know why it caused this behavior instead of just throwing an error or something?)